# Need help understanding deployment package for nodejs on AWS lambda

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda

I have a codebase in typescript which runs fine and creates the required js files. Next, my task is to create a deployment package out of it and deploy to AWS lambda. When i see the number of packages under node_modules folder, it shows me 450+ packages. Whereas an already deployed lambda function for the same code base has just around 50 packages under the node_modules.

Can someone help me with how to create the deployment package, with just the required packages under the node_modules folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow below steps to deploy lambda function with node_modules files

1. List below files in under folder any specific name let say "**app**"

   [image]
2. Zip "app" folder with all files

[image]

3. Login into aws account and create new lambda function and upload using below settings.
   Make sure **Handler** name must be like this **app/index.handler**, where "**app**" is zip folder name if you used different name then use that name.
   [image]
4. Upload file and click on save button
5. Done Enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks for answering in detail. I have been following the same process for deployments. This one is however a tricky situation, where-in i have a lambda function deployed already and also do have the code base for the functions. Here is my question. "The deployed lambda function has around 50 packages/folders when i export it, however when i build the codebase i get 400 plus folders inside the node_modules folder. The deployed function has size of 6MB, my deployment package post build and zipping is about 16MB.

Comment: See let say you install one package for eg. "request" right ?, request package have its own package.json which means that it has some dependencies on other packages, so when you install "request" then it will automatically install its dependency, you install one package but you can see in your node_modules there are many folder due to dependecies of modules

Comment: that makes sense. but the codebase is same. let's think it as two different individuals building the same code. the deployment package created by the other person has just around 50 or so folders in the node_module folder, whereas the one created by me has 400+ folders. I will check if there is a way to get the steps followed by the other person. I understand that without the full context it would be difficult to answer this question. However, ur answer definitely helped.  appreciate it!!